# Git push but with following conditions

Tags: git, bitbucket, aws-codecommit

I have the following requirement.

Git repo A (on BitBucket): all development is committed multiple times a day
Git repo B (on AWS CodeCommit): only specific commits from Repo A should go into it...

Example: I work on a block of code (have multiple commits into Repo A) and then when I'm happy with the progress and unit testing..etc.. I want to push all the changes into Repo B as a single commit (similar to a merge)

This is to keep the commit history of Repo B clean

Answer (score 0):

I would seperate branches for repo **A** and **B**. Then i would develop only on **A**-related branches.
When ready to push on **B**, I would `git cherry-pick` *new* commits from **A**-pushed-branch to **B**-related branch, and use `git rebase --interactive` to squash those to one commit and also adjust commit message. Important to cherry-pick, **do not try to merge** because differing branches history would not allow to procede.

Then just push it.

A lot of manual work thoe.